# Error 1146 and Error 1051 when dropping table and other commands

Tags: mysql

Comment/Answer if you need clarification.
**I am currently having an issue with MySQL error 1146.**

I have a schema called "cia_data" and have 3 files in my database--Query 1, SQL File 3, SQL File 5.

With the code shown in the attached video, I had two errors. The first error was with DROP TABLE new_table, which made sense as it said it was Unknown (error code 1051) and was executed a few times to ensure my imported table would not be counted. I then typed and executed SQL File 5 and had issues because of the table "not existing" even after I created it. Does anyone have a solution to this? I need to fix this error to move on in my project.

**Links**
Please see this video for more information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UitvpKdanzo
MySQL forum: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,705063,705069#msg-705069

**These changes were made to try to fix the issue:**

Three syntax errors ...

1. VISIBLE in the unique index

MySQL doesn't seem to like VISIBLE or INVISIBLE in CREATE TABLE, I'm unsure why. For creating an invisible index, this works ...

```
create table x( ..., unique index key_f(f), ...);
ALTER INDEX key_f INVISIBLE;
```

But in your case, VISIBLE is the default so it's not needed.

2. Missing semicolon at the end of the Create Table stmt
3. In the Insert stmt, SELECT instead of a left parenthesis at the beginning of the column list

**I still have the errors 1051 and 1146 even after making the previously mentioned changes.**

```
1051 - Unknown table 'cia_data.new_table'
1146 - Table 'cia_data.new_table' doesn't exist
```

**Here is the text:**

*****Query 1's Text*****

```
select * from `CIA_DATA`.`new_table`;
```

*****SQL File 3's Text*****

```
USE CIA_DATA;
DROP TABLE new_table;
CREATE TABLE new_table (
Water DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
Sanitation DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
GDP INT NOT NULL,
Life DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
Underweight DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
Literacy DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
Electricity DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
Country VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (GDP),
UNIQUE INDEX Country_UNIQUE (Country ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB

SELECT * FROM new_table;
```

*****SQL File 5's Text*****

```
desc CIA_DATA.new_table;

SELECT * FROM CIA_DATA.new_table;

INSERT INTO `CIA_DATA`.`new_table`
SELECT `Water`,
`Sanitation`,
`GDP`,
`Life`,
`Underweight`,
`Literacy`,
`Electricity`,
`Country`)
VALUES
(68.5,21.8,600,54.2,24.6,37.4,14,'Central_African_Republic');

COMMIT;
```

Edit:

Here is the corrected text for SQL File 5 for reference (using another country's data):

desc CIA_DATA.new_table;

SELECT * FROM CIA_DATA.new_table;

INSERT INTO `CIA_DATA`.`new_table`
SELECT `Water`,
`Sanitation`,
`GDP`,
`Life`,
`Underweight`,
`Literacy`,
`Electricity`,
`Country`)
VALUES
(68.5,21.8,600,54.2,24.6,37.4,14,'Central_African_Republic');

COMMIT;

Comment: *and have 3 files in my database--Query 1, SQL File 3, SQL File 5.* What are you speaking about? What "SQL File" - no such object type in MySQL.

Comment: *VISIBLE in the unique index MySQL doesn't seem to like VISIBLE or INVISIBLE in CREATE TABLE* AFAIR it is available since 8.0.23. *SQL File 5's Text* `INSERT .. SELECT .. VALUES` query type not exists.

Comment: @Akina I am referring to the SQL Script by SQL files 3 and 5. What edits should I make according to the second comment?

Comment: In "file 5" script you must remove `SELECT` keyword and replace it with opening parenthesis `(`. Also I recommend you to edit "file 3" - remove `VISIBLE` option from the index definition and set `VARCHAR(255)` datatype for `Country` column (if this column is not used in some foreign key relation and if this max. length won't effect in any other places). And I doubt that `COMMIT;` statement needed in "file 5" - in shown file it will act as "no operation".

Comment: I still get the following errors:

19:46:21 DROP TABLE new_table Error Code: 1051. Unknown table 'cia_data.new_table' 0.000 sec


19:46:22 desc CIA_DATA.new_table Error Code: 1146. Table 'cia_data.new_table' doesn't exist 0.000 sec

Comment: Use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_table`.

Comment: I cannot paste all the logs in these comments,  but it looks like the main issue is resolved for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected text so I can close this thread:

desc CIA_DATA.new_table;

SELECT * FROM CIA_DATA.new_table;

INSERT INTO `CIA_DATA`.`new_table`
SELECT `Water`,
`Sanitation`,
`GDP`,
`Life`,
`Underweight`,
`Literacy`,
`Electricity`,
`Country`)
VALUES
(68.5,21.8,600,54.2,24.6,37.4,14,'Central_African_Republic');

COMMIT;